# Python / external function gives wrong result

Tags: python

I have the following code in Python:

```
# .. some code
from app.ut.public import public

def get_public:
    f = open('log.txt','w')
    f.write(str(public.get()))
```

In the log.txt, I get the following: `{'item': '1'}`

Now, I'm going to the file public. The function `public.get()` do some operation of getting a value from external repository.

Here is the main of this class:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        result = public.get()
        print result
```

So it prints: `{'item': '1'}`.

The problem is when I change the external value. When I would run the main, it will give the correct result: `{'item': '2'}`.

But when I will run the `get_public` function, the value in log.txt is still `{'item': '1'}` (and the file was updated, meaning it a new version with the older and incorrect  result)

But main and get_public are calling the same function, and executed (Not a cache problem..). What the problem here?

Comment: It could be that you are not closing the file? Try `f.close()` after writing on it.

Comment: @iluengo: The same..